# Android logs does not show in android studio logcat window

Tags: android

Hear is definition:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  ...
}
```

And variable definition is :

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = BuildConfig.DEBUG;
```

Use

```
if(DEBUG)
   Log.i("TAG","...");
```

but there is no logs show in Logcat? Wish someome can give some clues

Comment: Why parse a string of true? You could simply assign a boolean value. That being said, that's not a [mcve]. I assume you are just logging. Is the logcat filtered?

Answer (score 1):

In your Android studio menu settings,

`Tools` -> `Android`, make sure the item `Enable ADB integration` is checked.

Another way to check is using the command line tools.

```
$ adb logcat -s "TAG"
```

Comment: Sometimes toggling that menu option fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

you DEBUG is true?

or

Computer restart  again
or

adb restart agin